# Rank-1 decomposability of symmetric tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, tensor

My question is about rank-1 decomposability of symmetric tensors over the reals.

Let $v_1,\dots,v_n\in\mathbb{R}^d$ be vectors. Construct the object:
$$
V=\sum_{j=1}^n \underbrace{v_j\otimes v_j\otimes \cdots\otimes v_j}_{k\text{ times}} \iff V_{i_1,\dots,i_k}=\sum_{j=1}^m v_{j,i_1}\cdots v_{j,i_k},
$$
for every $i_1,\dots,i_k\in\{1,2,\dots,d\}$.

This object is clearly a symmetric tensor, of order $k$. Now, let $M\neq 0$ be another symmetric tensor, not necessarily of this form:

**Question:**

Is there a $\lambda>0$ such that, the object,
$$
V(\lambda)=V+\lambda M
$$
admits a rank-1 decomposition, that is, there exists an integer $n'\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, and vectors $w_1,\dots,v_{n'}\in\mathbb{R}^d$, such that, $V(\lambda)$ can be decomposed as:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n'} \underbrace{w_j\otimes \cdots \otimes v_j}_{k\text{ times}},
$$
that is, for every $i_1,\dots,i_k\in\{1,2,\dots,d\}$:
$$
(V(\lambda))_{i_1,\dots,i_k} = \sum_{j=1}^{n'} w_{j,i_1}\cdots w_{j,i_k}?
$$

**Observations:**

1) Such a decomposition always holds if I focus on complex numbers. This is a result by Comon-Golub-Lim-Mourrain (*Symmetric tensors and symmetric tensor rank*).

2) Let $k=2$. Then the object $V$ is nothing but $\mathcal{V}^T\mathcal{V}$, where $\mathcal{V}$ is a matrix with rows $v_1,\dots,v_n$. Let $n>d$. Assuming ${\rm rank}(\mathcal{V})=d$, it is not hard to show, using Weyl's inequality on eigenvalue perturbations, that for every symmetric, non-zero $M\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, there is a $\lambda_0$ such that $\mathcal{V}^T \mathcal{V} + \lambda M$ is always positive semi-definite, for $\lambda\in[0,\lambda_0)$.

I am essentially interested in translating these ideas to higher-dimension/higher-order products.

Comment: Am I missing some kind of definiteness condition in the statement here? This is not true even in the $k=2$ case for positive *semi*definite real matrices (i.e., you sometimes need to take $\lambda = 0$ in that case).

Comment: @NathanielJohnston : No, you're right; and in fact, I've mentioned that in 2nd observation. For $n>d$ we need $v_1,\dots,v_n$ to span $\mathbb{R}^d$ so that we have positive definiteness; and can have $\lambda$ sufficiently small, but strictly positive.

I could not see how to impose such a restriction on the tensor itself.